# Writing sum in SQL, but other columns in GROUP By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a sum in one of my columns properties. But the rest I have to put in a group by. But is this correct? Or can you do it in a other way?

I have this:

```
SELECT 
    SU.[Vendor No_] as LeveranciersNR, V.Name as LeveranciersName, 
    SU.[Item No_], SU.[Reorder Cycle] as bestelfrequentie,
    SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy], 
    I.Description as procuctOmschrijving,
    SUM(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]) as Inkoopomzet
FROM 
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
JOIN
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
WHERE 
    SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2 
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY 
    VLE.[Vendor No_], SU.[Vendor No_], V.Name, SU.[Item No_], 
    SU.[Reorder Cycle], SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy],
    I.Description
ORDER BY 
    SU.[Location Code]
```

Thank you

But I get this as output:

```
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 110563  2M  AM  2   KOPP.BINDR.X FLEX 2 X 63,5 MM   -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 110565  2M  AM  2   KOPP.BINDR.X FLEX 5/4 X 44 MM   -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 110567  2M  AM  2   KOPP.BINDR.X FLEX 6/4 X 51 MM   -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 110569  2M  AM  2   KOPP.BINDR.X FLEX 2 X 57 MM -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75432   2M  AM  2   gebo 046206015 rep.kopp. 15 -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75433   2M  AM  2   gebo 046206022 rep.kopp. 22 -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75434   2M  AM  2   gebo 046206028 rep.kopp. 28 -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75435   2M  AM  2   gebo 046206035 rep.kopp. 35 -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75442   2M  AM  2   gebo 012522801 rep.kopp 1/2 -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75443   2M  AM  2   gebo 012522802 rep.kopp 3/4 -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75445   2M  AM  2   gebo 012522803 rep.kopp 1"  -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75449   2M  AM  2   gebo 012522804 rep.kopp 5/4 -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75450   2M  AM  2   gebo 012522805 rep.kopp 1 1/2   -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75451   2M  AM  2   gebo 012522806 rep.kopp 2"  -1141.70000000000000000000
3008    Gebo Armaturen GmbH 75452   2M  AM  2   gebo 012522807 rep.kopp 2 1/2   -1141.70000000000000000000
3047    Tasseron Sensors bv 906701  2M  AM  2   vaillant 287606 ntc voeler pl   -881.00000000000000000000
3047    Tasseron Sensors bv 906703  2M  AM  2   vaillant 287607 ntc voeler aa   -881.00000000000000000000
3047    Tasseron Sensors bv 913194  2M  AM  2   bosch 87229333160 ntc m6 r  -881.00000000000000000000
```

Comment: seems fine to me, did you try it?

Comment: This doesn't look like mysql.

Comment: ? I am using microsoft MSSQL 2014

Comment: @Lamak, Yes I have run the query. But maybe you can do it also on a other way

Comment: @NielsKing You could do it another way if you wanted another result, but is this what you want or not?

Comment: @Lamak, I just doubt about the results it gives. And also the double values by sum. For example the value: -1141.70000000000000000000

Comment: then you should take a look at your data with no aggregations first

Comment: It seems like you have to group by a bunch of column just for the purpose of viewing it. You can run a separate  subquery to sum the data, then join it to the other tables. You might need to use distinct on the select.

Comment: you realise that the sum is for the records represented by the grouping, so if you find the records that fit in with any of your displayed rows, their Purchase (LCY) will add up to the value Inkoopomzet - which you can check  - as pointed out by Lamak - you could also add COUNT(1) to count how many records in each group, and you could round your SUM using ROUND if you don't want so many decimals.  You need to try and tell us what you are trying to SUM

Comment: 1141.70000000000000000000 - you can check that by doing no grouping and selecting all of the grouping fields in a WHERE - it might take about 5 minutes to cut and paste the displayed values to match field names into a where, then comment out the grouping  (best use a copy of the query of course)

Comment: The result looks fine to me. It's the same sum per vendor as it should be. Use `FORMAT` if you want your numbers formatted.

Comment: Oke, thank you for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing inner join why not move the where clause criteria into the respective joins. It should run faster as the joins will create smaller result set:

```
SELECT 
    SU.[Vendor No_] as LeveranciersNR, V.Name as LeveranciersName, 
    SU.[Item No_], SU.[Reorder Cycle] as bestelfrequentie,
    SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy], 
    I.Description as procuctOmschrijving,
    SUM(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]) as Inkoopomzet
FROM 
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
JOIN
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2 
JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
GROUP BY 
    VLE.[Vendor No_], SU.[Vendor No_], V.Name, SU.[Item No_], 
    SU.[Reorder Cycle], SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy],
    I.Description
ORDER BY 
    SU.[Location Code]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution

Comment: @Niels King have you noticed any plan differences?

Comment: In the outcome it doesnt differ, the same result are returned - it gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script with less grouping, but it supposed to return the same result and there is not a fact that it will work faster.

```
;WITH VLE as (
    SELECT SUM([Purchase (LCY)]) as Inkoopomzet, [Vendor No_] 
    FROM [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry]
    WHERE [Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
    GROUP BY [Vendor No_]
)
SELECT 
    SU.[Vendor No_] as LeveranciersNR, V.Name as LeveranciersName, 
    SU.[Item No_], SU.[Reorder Cycle] as bestelfrequentie,
    SU.[Location Code], SU.[Reordering Policy], 
    I.Description as procuctOmschrijving,
    VLE.Inkoopomzet
FROM [Verploegen POC$Vendor] AS V
INNER JOIN VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
INNER JOIN [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
INNER JOIN [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
WHERE SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2 
ORDER BY SU.[Location Code];
```